# Multiply every element of an n-dimensional array by a number in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

In Ruby, is there a simple way to multiply every element in an n-dimensional array by a single number?

Such that: 
`[1,2,3,4,5].multiplied_by 2 == [2,4,6,8,10]`

and `[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]].multiplied_by 2 == [[2,4,6],[2,4,6]]`?

(Obviously I made up the `multiplied_by` function to distinguish it from `*`, which appears to concatenate multiple copies of the array, which is unfortunately not what I need).

Thanks!

Comment: The 2-dim array literals should be written like `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]`. Unfortunately, the 6 char threshold does not let me correct this.

Comment: Good spot, thanks. Apparently that limit doesn't apply to me, so I've changed it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The long-form equivalent of this is:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ].collect { |n| n * 2 }
```

It's not really that complicated. You could always make your `multiply_by` method:

```
class Array
  def multiply_by(x)
    collect { |n| n * x }
  end
end
```

If you want it to multiply recursively, you'll need to handle that as a special case:

```
class Array
  def multiply_by(x)
    collect do |v|
      case(v)
      when Array
        # If this item in the Array is an Array,
        # then apply the same method to it.
        v.multiply_by(x)
      else
        v * x
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess this answers my question - there's no 'precooked' way to do it. Even though it's simple, I'd always rather use a built-in function if there is one. No point reinventing the wheel - and possibly breaking it.

Comment: Yeah, there's no built-in method for this sort of thing, but the good news is adding patches to the core class is encouraged so long as you're not going to break an existing patch. To be careful you should always check to see if your method is defined before adding it on, possibly warning if it already exists.

Answer (score 3):

How about using `Matrix` class from ruby standard library?

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'matrix'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> m = Matrix[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
=> Matrix[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
irb(main):003:0> m*2
=> Matrix[[2, 4, 6], [2, 4, 6]]
irb(main):004:0> (m*3).to_a
=> [[3, 6, 9], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Facets, as usual, has some neat ideas:

```
>> require 'facets'
>> [1, 2, 3].ewise * 2
=> [2, 4, 6]

>> [[1, 2], [3, 4]].map { |xs| xs.ewise * 2 }
=> [[2, 4], [6, 8]]
```

http://rubyworks.github.com/facets/doc/api/core/Enumerable.html

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with multidimensional arrays. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, it does not. But what's wrong with a map? explicit is (usually) better than implicit.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with a map. But the data is coming from another (3rd party) application, so I have no control over its structure. Seeing as the operation is so simple, I thought I could get away with it in its current state, and avoid the overhead of converting it into a map only to perform a single operation then convert it back again.